# How to change cell's color dynamically by comparing schedule like tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have calendar like html tables , I wonder how can I change `td`cell's color dynamically.

For example,`yellow`means`firstst hospitalization`,`aqua`means`second hospitalization`

if the hospitalization which is `3 days or more` after `first hospitalization`,it was regarded`second hospitalization` and I would like to change its color to `aqua`

the example,if `3`,`5`,`6`is clicked,the desired result is below. `3` is first hospitalization date.

[image]

if some additional hospitalization is found out,for instance if `2` is found out,`5` will turn out to`second hospitalization`

[image]

Are there any way to realize it? is it necessary for `ajax`?
my attempt is below snippet.

Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("hospitalization");
  });
});
```

```css
.hospitalization {
    background-color:yellow;
}

.hospitalization_second {
    background-color:aqua;
}

td {
  padding:5px
  }
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <table>
        <td id="1">1</td>
        <td id="2">2</td>
        <td id="3">3</td>
        <td id="4">4</td>
        <td id="5">5</td>
        <td id="6">6</td>
        <td id="7">7</td>
        <td id="8">8</td>
        <td id="9">9</td>
        <td id="10">10</td>
        </table>
```

Comment: i did not get about color change between aqua and yellow how should be calculate

Answer (score 1):

If I correct understand you. yo had to do

```
$(function() {
  $("td").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('hospitalization')) {
      $(this).removeClass("hospitalization");
      $(this).addClass("hospitalization_second");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("hospitalization");
    }
  });
});
```